# sendgrid events post not working

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am trying to post **SendGrid** events back to my server. But I am not able to capture the data. When I try from the testing functionality, it is showing the response code as 200 and the posted data. But I am not able to capture it in my server side. I am using the following code

```
<?php
$postText = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print_r($postText);
$fh = fopen('/tmp/dump.log','a+');
fwrite($fh,print_r($postText),'true');
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Nothing is written to the file. I tried to write something to same file for testing and it is working. So I think the file has all the permissions.

Comment: use `$postText = trim(file_get_contents('php://input')); file_put_contents('/tmp/dump.log', $postText);` only

Comment: tried it also. But no effect. Another thing is that I tries to post using curl and it also not working

Comment: how you post the event to the server? I will be wrong also

Comment: There is a scheduled maintenance for the morning of Sep 19th - http://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/sections/200050018-SendGrid-Status.

Comment: curl -X POST -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"email":"john.doe@sendgrid.com","timestamp":1337197600,"smtp-id":"<4FB4041F.6080505@sendgrid.com>","event":"processed"}]' http://myurl.com/file.php

Comment: @BrettDeWoody seems like it is over.

Comment: Why not use their PHP library? Much easier to parse results. http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html

Comment: @SetSailMedia But I think it is only for sending mails.

Comment: Is there anything on your network that might be preventing your server from getting the requests?

Comment: Anyway this is fixed now. I have moved the text file to public_html path and added a true condition for print_r() and now it is dumping the data. Thanks guys for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you print the data by not passing second argument to the `print_r` function!

This line: `fwrite($fh,print_r($postText),'true');` should look like this instead: `fwrite($fh,print_r($postText, true));`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is already working, but wanted to share some sample code I use myself. (disclosure: I'm a SendGrid employee)

Very similar to your own code, but the RAW_POST_DATA global makes it pretty easy to fetch all POST data in one shot.

```
<?php

$fh = fopen("/tmp/sg_event.log", 'a+');
if ($fh) {
    fwrite($fh, print_r($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, true));
    fclose($fh);
}
?> ok
```